# How to remove a file in a running docker image and then save the image to load later?

Tags: docker

I'm trying to remove a file from a docker image and then export the docker image for use on another server.

I've done the following steps:

```
docker exec -it <name> sh
rm <file>
exit
docker commit <id> <newImageName>
docker save <newImageName> > newImageName.tar
```

When I untar the newImageName.tar, it still contains the file I rm'd above in one of the layers.

How can I remove a file from a running image and save off that image?

Thanks

Comment: after `docker commit <id> <name>` you have an image called name, so then it is `docker save name > newimagename.tar` is it what you do?

Comment: And `docker commit <id> <name>`, that container `<id>` should be the last container you have stopped (`docker ps -a -q |head -n1`)

Comment: by the way, it should `docker commit id newname`, as name is the name if the active container you `docker exec` in

Answer (score 1):

Remove the file with `docker exec` and `rm`, and then export the container with `docker export`.  When you restore the container with `docker import` the file will not be there.

When you use `docker commit` you are creating another layer over the previous ones, and the file will still exist in the previous layer tarballs because Docker images are built upon the concept of layers.  When you `docker load` and run the image, the file will not be there.

If your issue is the file being present in the tarballs because a false positive from a virus scan, then use `docker export`.

Answer (score -1):

so it should be

`docker exec -it container_id_or_name sh`

now you delete a file

`rm file`

then you leave the container

`ctrl d`

or

`exit`

now you commit

`docker commit container_id_or_name myuser:myimage`

and

you save

`docker save myuser:myimage > newImageName.tar`

see the docs

https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/commit/

https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/save/

Comment: I follow those instructions - yet, when you explode the newImageName.tar file, and explode the layer.tar files inside there, the file I removed, still exists.

Comment: This is the docker image I'm messing with: https://hub.docker.com/r/appbaseio/mirage/

I'm trying to remove ./mirage/node_modules/fsevents/node_modules/tar/test/cb-never-called-1.0.1.tgz because it won't pass a virus scan because it lacks a proper end of file.. for good reason, i assume, it's a test file.

Either way, I delete it in the running image, commit, etc., etc it's still there in the saved output tar file.

Comment: Looks like I either need a squash or an export/import because it would appear export flattens the layers (which one layer still contains said file.)